# Why my phones won't show Beidou/BDS signal

Tags: gps, gps-tracking, glonass

I tried using apps like [GPSTest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.gpstest&hl=en_US&gl=US) and [GPS Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.slybeaver.gpsinfo&hl=en_US&gl=US) to see what GNSS my phone actually uses. I can see GPS and GLONASS on a Moto Z3 Play, and GPS, GLONASS, and GALILEO on a OnePlus N10 5G. Both phones should also support the Beidou system, so I'm wondering if there is anything preventing these phones from seeing/using Beidou/BDS